# Providing Dynamic Hyper links in jasper server report embedded in webapplication to route within webapplication

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm new to Jasper, I'm building a report and embedding it in my web application, which consist of List of names from my database, I want those names to be hyperlink so that if the user click on that name he must be able to view the details page about that person in my web application. Can some one please let me know is this feature possible ?

Comment: Of course this is possible. Give us some details regarding your design and integration. How are you embedding your report with your web application?

Comment: Hi viki thank you. I'm using joomla frame work(php) and using visualize.js to embed.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah u have to create object id for each user and place that user with in html hyperlink tag then call function for showing the user page based on object id.

Comment: Aijaz thank you for your replay. Yes I've object id for each user. my question is can I have some place holder in html link which I provide, And  is it possible to pick it up dynamically during execution?